# How do I display a UIImageView via a Switch on state? Then...how do I add constraints to the UIImageView to either center it or such?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, constraints, uiswitch

I am trying to have a UIImageView (centered horizontally in the viewController) with a UISwitch inside of it.
When the UIswitch is turned to the ON position - a second UIImageView should appear to the left of the original UIImageView, while the constraints should make it so that both UIImageViews are centered horizontally.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically create the second `UIImageView` or is it already set up in IB?

Comment: I added the outlet for the UIImageViews and the outlet and action for the UISwitch.  I can hide/show the image view correctly via the switch - but I dont know so much about programmatically dealing with horizontal constraints in the container.

Comment: @Aaron - the UIImageViews are all created in IB beforehand.

Comment: I guess - I am asking mainly about working with constraints.  I will hookup the constraints to an IBAction of the UISwitch.  and I want to define the constraints of the UIImageViews and have no clue which functions to use or how the syntax for programmatic constraints are.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but the easiest is to simply use a centered horizontal UIStackView that contains only a single imageView.  When the switch is flipped add the second imageView to the stackView by calling [insertArrangedSubview(*:at:)*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview/1616237-insertarrangedsubview) and the stackView will take care of maintaining the centering and any requested spacing.  Similarly when the switch is off just call [removeArrangedSubview(:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview/1616235-removearrangedsubview) and everything goes back into place.

If you are not on iOS 9 and don't have UIStackView you can just drag an IBOutlet to the view that you want to move's centerX constraint and add to its .constant property and animate layoutIfNeeded to have it slide to the right.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController{
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageViewCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
        let padding = CGFloat(10)
        @IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {
            imageViewCenterXConstraint.constant = imageView.frame.size.width / 2 + padding
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded()}
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JoshHorman beautiful idea about stackview. I am on iOS 10 and XCode 8 with Swift 3.  Would you be kind enough to provide example code please? thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited the answer with example code to animate the imageView to the right.  You can do the same thing in the opposite direction to animate the new view to go to the left.